# How can I replace rich box's text, from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create basic text editor but I got confused about replace operation. The user will input the specific value and new value in the second form then  if first form's Rich Box text contains the specific value then replace the specific value with new value. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

2 Options:

1. Find/replace can just be a hanging panel instead of a separate dialog/window. So all the controls are in the same form, you can simply get `.Text` of the RichTextBox and do your replace operations.
2. Expose your RichTextBox via a public property in your main form. Pass the reference of this main form to your Find/Replace dialog/window, which will use this reference to do operations on the public property.

Comment: thank you for your interest. Find/replace operations should be hanging on the new panel cuz There are also other operations at the first panel.I declared richTextBox as  public at the first form then I created instance of the first form at second form then when I want to pass first form's richtextbox  in the second form it returns empty string for richBoxText :(

Comment: _then I created instance of the first form at second form_  Don't create an instance of the first form in the second form; **PASS** a reference to the first form into the second form.  This is stated in Sunil's option #2.